# opening the image in a big window using ng-carousel bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular5

I am showing a slider including many images in a websites using Angular 4. Since the slider is in a small part of the webpage, I want to put some kind of click or an option that the image can be shown in more big screen or window. the image could be clickable or maybe the slider opens in a more big window or dialog. Here is my code of HTML part:

```html
 <ngb-carousel>
     <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let photo of array">
        <img class="img-fluid w-full" [src]="photo"   (error)="errorHandler($event)" alt="No image found">
     </ng-template>
 </ngb-carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular2-lightbox](https://github.com/themyth92/angular2-lightbox), it say angular2 but it works till 5 (source: I use it in an angular5 project)

In your ts file

```
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
    galleries: Gallery[];
    lightboxObj: any[];

    constructor(
        private staffService: PageService, 
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.staffService.getOne('galleries').subscribe(
            galleries => {
                this.galleries = galleries;
                this.lightboxObj = this.galleries.map(gallery => {
                    return {
                        src: gallery.url,
                        caption: gallery.name
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    }

    openLightbox( index: number ) {
        this._lightboxService.open(this.lightboxObj, index);
    }
}
```

and the html is done like:

```
<div class="row galleries">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" *ngFor="let gallery of galleries; let i=index"> 
           <div (click)="openLightbox(i)" class="bg-image clickable" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + gallery.url + ')'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

notice the `click` event and the index `i`

Comment: I get an error while i add "private staffService: PageService" in my constructor.

Comment: thats the service in my application who send the gallery data. In your application it should have another name.
Its in the example as a reference, the only important thing is the lightboxObj array.